# What is page.reload([options]) in Playwright?

Tags: end-to-end, playwright

I couldn't find any detail explanation about the page.reload() method in Playwright. Is there anyone who can explain it to me in detail? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: It should reload the current page. Like when you press F5 in your browser.

Answer (score 4):

Am I correct?

```
1. page.reload()  ---  just reload the webpage

2. page.reload(timeout=0)  ---  reload the webpage, disable timeout

3. page.reload(timeout=30000)  ---  reload the webpage, timeout = 30 seconds

4. page.reload(waitUntil='load')  ---  reload the webpage until consider operation to be finished

5. page.reload(timeout=0, waitUntil='load')  ---  .......
```

Comment: You should add some more context to the answer that you've given